# Dropdown boxes appearing off screen

Tags: jquery, css, model-view-controller, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am having an issue with dropdown boxes in my current MVC project. It seems that when the page has been scrolled that the option box is offset and appears off screen. I have read around and found a few people having the same problem but I have been unable to find a solution.

This is the code that I am using to create the dropdown box.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div><label class="control-label">What injuries were sustained?</label></div>
    <div class="text-muted">Select as many as necessary.</div>
        @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
            .Name("injuries")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", @id = "injuries"})
            .DataTextField("Name")
            .DataValueField("ID")
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                   read.Action("GetInjuries", "Incident");
                });
             })
          )
    </div>
</div>
```

In this I am using a Kendo multiselect but I have looked through and any dropdown element that is using list items suffers from the issue.

I have an example image where I have zoomed out so the issue is visible. When zoomed all the way in and the user has scrolled to the box it is completely of screen.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tried setting a `width` on the element in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Remove any unecessary `<div>` from around the `<label>` and your "input" tags. These will affect your styling. Here is what your outputted html should look something like:

```
<div>
  <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1">
</div>
```

If that doesn't make things tidier. Make your inputs parent have a `position: relative` and the dropdown element a `position: absolute` then add `top:0`. And, it should be closer. If you set the parent div to have a width of a number as a percentage. Then width of 100% for  the child elements (input, dropdown) then these won't go astray horizontally also.